# How to split string and insert the second part into another column

Tags: mysql

I have a column which contains string in the following format: `strin1/string2`. I need to take `string2` part and insert it into another column, `string3`. I am aware of `substr( )` function, but this function would require me to know the index of the character & in my case, this is not know.

Comment: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
substr(col, instr(col, '/')+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('string1/string2','/',-1);
```

like that????